# IOS sqlite full text search, memory leaks.

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search

I am implementing FTS in IOS project using sqlite. I have followed the following process:

1: created an new Cocoa Touch Static library.
2: Added the SQLite source files (sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h) to the project
3: Enabled SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
4: Added this Xcode framework-project as a whole to the Xcode iOS app-project.

It's working fine but, it is giving 42 leaks after analysing. To implement this I am using folioing configuration:

xcode 5,
Base SDK 7,
target 5.0
LLVM 5.0

Let me know is am I doing anything wrong?